# Xcode server does not show xcode configured git repository

Tags: xcode, xcode6, git-remote, repository, xcode-server

I'm setting up an XCode Server to get some CI Bots going for a project I'm doing.

I have Xcode (6.1.1) configured to connect to a remote git repo, and everything works fine. All VCS operations works as expected.

I then installed XCode server (4.0.3) and pointed it to my Xcode application. It seems to be happy and recognises my Developer Team etc.

Now I was under the impression that the git repo I have configured in xcode would show up under the 'Repositories' tab on Xcode Server, but this list is empty.

What am I missing here ? Is this an overall bad plan (connect to remote git, have bots pull and build my stuff) ?

Cheers,
Niklas

Comment: having same issue..any luck with it???